# Assign user property to variable in firebase and react

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I call a function from `render()` as so:

```
<Avatar src={GetUserAvatar(item.createdBy)} />
```

The function should return the url to the user's photo:

```
function GetUserAvatar(userId) {
  let userAvatar =
    "https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png";
  db.collection("users")
    .doc(userId)
    .get()
    .then(function(doc) {
      userAvatar = doc.data().photoURL;
    });
  // Still returns original assignment instead of data().photoURL
  return userAvatar;
```

How can I get `data().photoURL` to get returned from the function?

Answer (score 2):

Fetching data from firestore is async, so you'll need to assign `photoURL` to the state and trigger the api call, which will set the value, on button click:

```
const Avatar = () => {
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState("");

  const getUserAvatar = async userId => {
    let userAvatar =
      "https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png";
    db.collection("users")
      .doc(userId)
      .get()
      .then(function(doc) {
        setImageUrl(doc.data().photoURL);
      });
  };

  // Assuming you have the user id to pass in
  return (
    <>
      <Avatar src={imageUrl} />
      <button onClick={() => getUserAvatar(user.id)}>Get avatar</button>
    </>
  );
};
```